# jQuery changing ID via attr and then calling it

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr

I'm creating a UserCP for my URL shortener website in PHP, however I have come to a halt as I've now got a little problem which I cannot solve.

I want to make a user easily update a URL by using Javascript's library, Jquery. So far, if you click the "edit" button (see below) the text turns into text fields so it's editable! Which is great. on the process on making it into a text field, I've used the attr() function to change the class name and ID of the button that made the text into a text field. Using the new ID that I have assigned will send a $.POST to a PHP script. I hope you understand, I'll display the code below for you to see!

```
<?php while($list = $listURLs->fetch_array()) { ?>

<td id="longURL<?= $list['ID']; ?>"><a rel="tooltip" title="<?= $list['longURL']; ?>" target="_blank" href="<?= $list['longURL']; ?>"><?= substr($list['longURL'],0,25); ?></a></td>
        <td id="shortURL<?= $list['ID']; ?>"><input type='text' class='span2' onmouseover="(this.select())" value='http://smurl.es/<?= $list['shortURL']; ?>'/></td>
        <td><?= $list['type']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $time; ?></td>
        <td><?= $list['hits']; ?></td>
        <td><button id="edit<?= $list['ID']; ?>" class='btn btn-warning btn-small' rel='tooltip' title='Edit'><i class="icon icon-edit"></i></button>&nbsp;<button id="del<?= $list['ID']; ?>" class='btn btn-danger btn-small' rel='tooltip' title='Delete'><i class="icon icon-trash"></i></button></td>
    </tr>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("button#edit<?= $list['ID']; ?>").click(function() {
            $('#longURL<?= $list['ID']; ?>').html("<input type='text' value='<?= $list['longURL']; ?>' />");
            $('#shortURL<?= $list['ID']; ?>').html("<div class='input-prepend'><span class='add-on'>http://smurl.es/</span><input id='prependedInput' type='text' value='<?= $list['shortURL']; ?>' class='span1' /></div>");
            $("button#edit<?= $list['ID']; ?>").attr({"class": "btn btn-info btn-small test", "data-original-title": "Click to Save", "id": "save<?= $list['ID']; ?>"});

            });


            $('button#save<?= $list['ID']; ?>').click(function() {
                             alert("testing - DEBUG"); // Save code here
            });
        </script>
    <?php 
        }
    }
     ?>
```

So if you're still confused a little, I'd just like to know how can I call an ID that I have made via attr or possibly a different function?

I've checked my console, I don't see any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You have to prevent the default `onclick`-behaviour with `event.preventDefault`:

```
$("button#edit<?= $list['ID']; ?>").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#longURL<?= $list['ID']; ?>').html("<input type='text' value='<?= $list['longURL']; ?>' />");
    $('#shortURL<?= $list['ID']; ?>').html("<div class='input-prepend'><span class='add-on'>http://smurl.es/</span><input id='prependedInput' type='text' value='<?= $list['shortURL']; ?>' class='span1' /></div>");
    $("button#edit<?= $list['ID']; ?>").attr({"class": "btn btn-info btn-small test", "data-original-title": "Click to Save", "id": "save<?= $list['ID']; ?>"});
});
```

Comment: Hi there, I don't quite understand what I'm going to do with that code? what will I use to call a different button, I mean how will it help? I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: Sorry, can anyone please answer my question? I really need to know! :(